# Retraining model starts with higher loss than it finished with last session

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I am training a model for a denoising task.

Every time i train it the first loss in the new training session is much higher than the loss i finished with before. for example after first training:

[image]

Then when i wanted to train it for 100 more epochs:

[image]

`20x` higher loss.

Why does it happen?

Edit:
Here is the loss graphed. You can clearly see that after epoch 2500 there is a massive increase in the loss:

[image]

Added the training loop here:

```
num_epochs = 500

criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss()

sgd_params = {
    "lr": 0.30,
    "momentum": 0.9
}

lin_optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(lin_model.parameters(), lr=0.30, momentum=0.9)
sta_optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(sta_model.parameters(), lr=0.30, momentum=0.9)
ref_optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(ref_model.parameters(), lr=0.30, momentum=0.9)

_, val_clean, val_noisy = util.lincomb_generate_data(batch_size*10, B, K, functions, sample_offset=sample_offset, noise_type="gaussian", noise_mean=noise_mean, noise_std=noise_std)

print("STARTED TRAINING")

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    print("Current epoch {}\r".format(epoch), end="")
    # generate data returns the x-axis used for plotting as well as the clean and noisy data
    _, t_clean, t_noisy = util.lincomb_generate_data(batch_size, B, K, functions, sample_offset=sample_offset, noise_type="gaussian", noise_mean=noise_mean, noise_std=noise_std)

    # ===================forward=====================
    lin_output = lin_model(t_noisy.float())
    sta_output = sta_model(t_noisy.float())
    ref_output = ref_model(t_noisy.float())

    lin_loss = criterion(lin_output.float(), t_clean.float())
    sta_loss = criterion(sta_output.float(), t_clean.float())
    ref_loss = criterion(ref_output.float(), t_clean.float())
    
    lin_loss_list.append(lin_loss.data)
    sta_loss_list.append(sta_loss.data)
    ref_loss_list.append(ref_loss.data)
    # ===================backward====================
    lin_optimizer.zero_grad()
    sta_optimizer.zero_grad()
    ref_optimizer.zero_grad()

    lin_loss.backward()
    sta_loss.backward()
    ref_loss.backward()

    lin_optimizer.step()
    sta_optimizer.step()
    ref_optimizer.step()
    
    val_lin_loss = F.mse_loss(lin_model(val_noisy.float()), val_clean.float())
    val_sta_loss = F.mse_loss(sta_model(val_noisy.float()), val_clean.float())
    val_ref_loss = F.mse_loss(ref_model(val_noisy.float()), val_clean.float())

print("DONE TRAINING")
```

edit 2: bump

Comment: Could you show your code for saving/loading your model and/or the code you use to train/retrain the model? There are a number of factors which could be causing this issue. Hard to speculate without seeing how you've implemented your training/retraining and model saving/loading

Comment: Do you use any learning rate planners (i.e. `ReduceLROnPlateau`) ? Looks like you start off with a high learning rate that diverges and then the learning rate gets regulated and loss converges.

Comment: @BobsBurgers I use jupyter notebook so i dont actually save or load but just re-running the same block with a different number of epochs.

Comment: @DominikFicek I didnt use any LR planners